# PDF Icon Not showing in WSS Upload documents and pdf files are not appearing in search results

Tags: sharepoint, pdf, wss, ifilter

I have tried the following articles to display the pdf icon next to uploaded documents in WSS 3.0

1. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/832809
2. http://servergrrl.blogspot.in/2008/02/adding-pdf-icons-to-wss-30-and-what.html
3. http://servergrrl.blogspot.in/2008/02/adding-pdf-icons-to-wss-30-and-what.html

But still no luck.

Can anyone Help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its Working Now,

I have made `IIS reset`.

And to make pdf files appear in search I have made my `Full site crawl`.

Now both of things are working for me.